# How to write a for loop as a condition of a while loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

First of all, I am really new to MATLAB so I'm not sure how to create multiple concurrent conditions for executing a while loop. I have a1(i)x + a2(i)y ≤ b(i) for i = 1, . . ., 16 and when this statement is true, it will execute, for example x=x+1. I have tried to code for that idea:

```
while (for i=i:16
      a1(i)*x + a2(i)*y < b(i);
       end)
   x=x+1;
end
```

But of course, that code is wrong, I just want to make the whole for loop as the condition of the while loop. So how can I fix my code to do that? Thank you!

Comment: It's rather unclear what you want the code to do. Could you please [edit] the question to provide a more thorough explanation, preferably with a [mcve], i.e. include sample input and output. Yes, you can wrap loops in loops, something like `while x<3; for ii=1:3; a(ii) = ii;end;x=x+1;end` works fine.

Comment: It looks like you could use `while true; for ii = 1:16 (...); if <condition>; break;end;end;x=x+1;end`; take a look at the [documentation page of `break`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `all` or `any`, depending on your desired output

```
while any( a1 * x + a2 * y < b )
    x = x + 1;
end

% or

while all( a1 * x + a2 * y < b )
    x = x + 1;
end
```

Read up on [vectorisation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) to see why you can usually avoid loops in MATLAB